# Finding the length of the longest increasing path in a matrix

Tags: algorithms, data-structures, dynamic-programming

**Problem:**

Given a matrix, find the length of the longest increasing path. We can move up, down, left, or right.

**Example:**

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1&2&3&4\\2&2&3&4\\3&2&3&4\\4&5&6&7
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Output: 7

Longest path is 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7

**Question:**

I am not sure if this post is relevant to this site. I having some trouble coming up with a system to solve this problem. I am not too advanced with programming, I am more of a mathematician by trade but I know some stuff about data structure and algorithms.

If possible, an ideal answer for me would be a step by step guide in solving this problem. My initial thought was to find the smallest number in the $(i, j)$ position and start with the first $(i,j)$ position that was found. Then check up, down, left, right to see which number is larger. But then I thought okay what if there are more than 1 position that is larger? I am pretty stuck with this so any help would be useful.

I found solutions to this online but reading other peoples code is nauseating and I don't find it useful at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an $O(nm \log nm)$ solution, where $n,m$ are the dimensions of the matrix. Later we improve it to an optimal $O(nm)$ solution.

Let $A[i_1j_1],\ldots,A[i_{nm}j_{nm}]$ be the entries of $A$ in non-decreasing order; the indices $i_tj_t$ can be computed in time $O(nm\log nm)$. We will compute a new matrix $B$ with the same dimensions such that $B[ij]$ is the length of the longest increasing part ending at $A[ij]$. We compute the entries of $B$ in the order $B[i_1j_1],\ldots,B[i_{nm}j_{nm}]$, using the formula
$$
B[ij] =
1 + \max_{\substack{i'j' \sim ij \\ A[i'j'] < A[ij]}} B[i'j'],
$$
where $i'j' \sim ij$ means that $A[i'j']$ is a neighbor of $A[ij]$, and we set $B[ij] = 1$ if the maximum is over the empty set.

The answer is simply the maximum entry of $B$. You can find an actual longest increasing sequence by starting with a maximum entry of $B$, say equal to $\ell$, finding a neighbor equal to $\ell-1$, then a neighbor equal to $\ell-2$, and so on until hitting a neighbor equal to $1$. This gives you a longest increasing sequence in reverse order.

As an example, consider your matrix
$$
A = \begin{pmatrix}
1&2&3&4\\2&2&3&4\\3&2&3&4\\4&5&6&7
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
We can order the entries as follows (there are many possible orders, since the entries are not distinct):
$$
A[1,1],A[1,2],A[2,1],A[2,2],A[3,2],A[1,3],A[2,3],A[3,1],\\A[3,3],A[1,4],A[2,4],A[3,4],A[4,1],A[4,2],A[4,3],A[4,4].
$$
We now compute $B$ in the same order:
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1& & & \\
 & & & \\
 & & & \\
 & & &
\end{pmatrix},
\begin{pmatrix}
1&2& & \\
 & & & \\
 & & & \\
 & & &
\end{pmatrix},
\begin{pmatrix}
1&2& & \\
2& & & \\
 & & & \\
 & & &
\end{pmatrix},
\begin{pmatrix}
1&2& & \\
2&1& & \\
 & & & \\
 & & &
\end{pmatrix}, \\
\begin{pmatrix}
1&2& & \\
2&1& & \\
 &1& & \\
 & & &
\end{pmatrix},
\begin{pmatrix}
1&2&3& \\
2&1& & \\
 &1& & \\
 & & &
\end{pmatrix},
\begin{pmatrix}
1&2&3& \\
2&1&2& \\
 &1& & \\
 & & &
\end{pmatrix},
\begin{pmatrix}
1&2&3& \\
2&1&2& \\
3&1& & \\
 & & &
\end{pmatrix}, \\
\begin{pmatrix}
1&2&3& \\
2&1&2& \\
3&1&3& \\
 & & &
\end{pmatrix},
\begin{pmatrix}
1&2&3&4\\
2&1&2& \\
3&1&3& \\
 & & &
\end{pmatrix},
\begin{pmatrix}
1&2&3&4\\
2&1&2&3\\
3&1&3& \\
 & & &
\end{pmatrix},
\begin{pmatrix}
1&2&3&4\\
2&1&2&3\\
3&1&3&4\\
 & & &
\end{pmatrix}, \\
\begin{pmatrix}
1&2&3&4\\
2&1&2&3\\
3&1&3&4\\
4& & &
\end{pmatrix},
\begin{pmatrix}
1&2&3&4\\
2&1&2&3\\
3&1&3&4\\
4&5& &
\end{pmatrix},
\begin{pmatrix}
1&2&3&4\\
2&1&2&3\\
3&1&3&4\\
4&5&6&
\end{pmatrix},
\begin{pmatrix}
1&2&3&4\\
2&1&2&3\\
3&1&3&4\\
4&5&6&7
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
We conclude that the answer is $7$. Retracing our steps, we highlight the following path in $B$, which corresponds to the longest increasing sequence in $A$ (accidentally, having exactly the same values):
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1& & & \\
2& & & \\
3& & & \\
4&5&6&7
\end{pmatrix}.
$$

---

We can implement essentially the same solution in time $O(nm)$ using DFS. We go over the entries of $B$ in some arbitrary order, attempting to use the same recurrence formula we had before:
$$
B[ij] =
1 + \max_{\substack{i'j' \sim ij \\ A[i'j'] < A[ij]}} B[i'j'].
$$
If we are trying to access an entry $B[i'j']$ which hasn't already been computed we compute it recursively. Conversely, once an entry $B[ij]$ has been computed, there is no need to compute it again.

This can be implemented using the following pseudocode:

```
compute-B-matrix:
  initialize B to be empty
  for 1 <= i <= n and 1 <= j <= m:
     if B[i,j] is empty, call compute-entry(i,j)

compute-entry(i,j):
  let S = { neighbors (i',j') of (i,j) such that A[i',j'] < A[i,j] }
  if S is empty:
     set B[i,j] = 1
  if S is non-empty:
    for every (i',j') in S:
      if B[i',j'] is empty, call compute-entry(i',j')
    set B[i,j] = 1 + max({ B[i',j'] : (i',j') in S })
```

This solution essentially amounts to computing a topological ordering of a digraph naturally associated with $A$. Details left to the reader.

Comment: I like your solution I just have a few questions. As I understand it, we first re-write the matrix $A$ in increasing order. Then construct a matrix $B$. I don't fully understand the details of how to construct the matrix $B$. Am I correct with the first step though?

Comment: I don't rewrite the matrix $A$. I just figure out the order of the entries, which I follow when filling the matrix $B$.

Comment: Okay, I am confused. Let me ask about the first sentence then. When you say arrange the entries of the matrix in non-decreasing order. Do you mean I create a matrix whose entries are non-decreasing entries of A? Sorry I am a bit slow with this.

Comment: What I actually do is take all pairs of indices $(i,j)$, for $1 \leq i \leq n$ and $1 \leq j \leq m$, and arrange them in nondecreasing order of the corresponding entry of $A$. How you implement that is up to you.

Comment: Okay so let me see if I understand. If I have a matrix $$A = \begin{pmatrix} 10 & 5 & 1\\ 2 & 10 & 1\\ 2& 9 & 10 \end{pmatrix}$$ Then for your first sentence I create say $$A' = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 & 2\\ 2 & 5 & 9\\ 10 & 10 & 10 \end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: This won't be very helpful, since what you really want to know is where the entries came from. I suggest spending some time with the algorithm and trying to understand what it's attempting to do.

Comment: Okay, I am trying just a bit unclear for me.

Comment: After you re construct the matrix A for each entry how do we know the length of the longest path?

Comment: It's the maximum value of an entry of B.

Comment: Why does the proposed algorithm to compute $B$ in arbitrary order work? $B$ values for higher values depend on $B$ values for lower values, so you can't compute the first before the second. I don't see how this can be fixed except by keeping distances between cells (each `B[i,j]` holding a list of cells with the length of the longest path to that cell) and doing a transitive closure, which is probably more expensive than sorting by value.

Comment: Another fix: keep a priority queue of cells sorted in increasing value. Initialize it to the cells none of whose neighbors have a lower value. Now replace the first cell by its unvisited higher-valued neighbors and repeat. This may be cheaper than sorting *all* cells in advance. If the cells aren't visited in order of increasing value. the algorithm is incorrect.

Comment: @reinierpost Perhaps you'll find it easier to consider the topological order formulation of the algorithm. Draw an edge from $a$ to its neighbor $b$ if $a<b$. You can find a topological order in linear time, and use this order instead of the sorted order.

Comment: I am still really confused by your algorithm, is there any way we can simplify it more?

Comment: I'm afraid that's the best I can do.

Comment: Okay, no problem I am sure your solution is great. I just dont think many people will understand it.

Comment: I didn't realise topological sort can be done in $O(n)$. Then indeed my apporach is useless.